# How can I check out-of-sight characters in UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` that shrinks and expands when user input text. If the textfield's width reach the screen width, I want it to be right-aligned so user can see the last input characters. In other circumstance, I want it to be left-aligned.

Because the textfield's maximum width is not exactly the same with screen, I need to find a way to check if it has characters out of visible area.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try checking the width of the string that is in the field and comparing it to the width of the field itself. It would look something like this -

```
CGSize textSize = [self.field.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.field.font}];

// If the text is larger than the field
if (textSize.width > self.field.bounds.size.width) {
    // There is text that is not visible in the field. 
}
```

This is fairly rough, but should get you close.